# How to filter table with JQuery. Using OR and AND conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, tablefilter

I have a table which I would like to apply filtering to.  The user can choose to filter based on multiple terms separated by a comma.  These terms will be the OR conditions.  I would also like the user to be able to put a plus sign between two terms and have this as the 'AND' conditions.

For example:

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          ID         |        NAME      |       DEPT       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         BOB      |      Sales       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          2          |        SALLY     |      Sales       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          3          |         BOB      |    HouseKeeping  |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          4          |        SALLY     |    HouseKeeping  |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

Now if I put the following search terms: BOB, SALLY+HOUSEKEEPING

I would want the following results

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          ID         |        NAME      |       DEPT       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         BOB      |       Sales      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          3          |         BOB      |    HouseKeeping  |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          4          |        SALLY     |    HouseKeeping  |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

As stated the comma acts as an 'OR' operator and the plus sign acts as an 'AND' operator.

I have sort of got this working with the following code but I am having a few issues which I don't know how to get round.  Maybe I am not doing this correctly, please tell me if so and point me in the correct direction.

The below code will give me the results I want provided they are in this order. i.e. searchterm1, searchterm2+searchterm3

```
$("#myInput").on("keyup", function () {
    var value = $(this).val().trim().toLowerCase();
    var orConditions;
    var andConditions;

    if (value.indexOf(',') > -1) {
        orConditions= value.split(',');                 
        orConditions= orConditions.filter(r=>r != '');
    }

    $("#myTable tr").filter(function () {
        $(this).hide().css('.excludeFromFilter');
    });

    $("#myTable tr").not('.excludeFromFilter').filter(function () {
        if (value != '') {
            if (orConditions) {
                var length = orConditions.length;
                var containsText = false;
                while (length--) {
                    if (orConditions[length].indexOf('+') > -1) {
                        andConditions = orConditions[length].split('+');
                        andConditions = andConditions.filter(r=>r != '');
                        if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(andConditions[0]) > -1 &&
                            $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(andConditions[1]) > -1) {
                                containsText = true;
                        }
                        else {
                             containsText = false;
                         }
                     }
                     else {
                         if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(orConditions[length]) > -1) {
                             containsText = true;
                         }
                     }
                 }
                 $(this).toggle(containsText);
             }
             else {
                 $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
             }
         }
         else {
             $(this).show().not('.excludeFromFilter')
         }
     });
     var $table = $('.transSummary1');
     $table.floatThead('reflow');
 });
```

The problems that I am facing are:

- If the first term is an 'AND' condition then all rows are hidden (I know this is because the '+' is only being taken into consideration if there are 'OR' conditions, but don't know how to fix it so it doesn't matter which is first i.e. an 'OR' or 'AND')
- If I add another 'OR' term after the 'AND' then this other term is not taken into account
- How can I modify this to allow more than two 'AND' conditions i.e. searchterm1+searchterm2+searchterm3

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Let me know if the answer I provided works for ya. If you looked at it within the last 30 minutes, know that I have revised it a few times. I've submitted the final edit.

Answer (score 1):

---

**UPDATE**: I have fixed the logic to match your specifications as mentioned in the comment below. I've also added trimming to the strings to ignore left and right spaced padding on each parameter.

---

Here's the jquery code written out. Please note that this can be shortened and optimized however, it's a quick and dirty way of accomplishing what you're looking to do. Also note that I've added a variable in the `keyup` event handler on line 5 which you can set to false if you'd like search values to respect case sensitivity. I made it so that the first value is always considered an 'OR' value however, if the first value is prefixed with a `+`, only the AND handler will be considered.

Please see the jsfiddle example I have included below the code which contains the HTML ID's & classes respectively. Note that I added `class="avoid"` to the `<tr>` table rows to exclude them from the row iteration.

CSS

```
table {
  width:100%;
  border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
}
table tr td {
  border:1px solid #CCC;
  text-align:center;
}
#results { text-align: center; }
#filter-preview, .text-left { text-align:left; }
#caseinsensitive, .inline { display:inline-block; margin:3px; text-align:left;  }
.input { display:inline-block; width:70%; }
input {
  height:25px;
  width:100%;
  padding:5px;
  vertical-align:middle;
  border-radius:15px;
}

.hide td {
  background-color:rgb(255,0,0);
  /* Uncomment below to make rows hide. */
  /* display: none; */
}

.or, .and {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:center;
  padding:3px;
  text-align:center;
  margin-right:3px;
  border-radius:5px;
}

.or {
  background-color: rgb(198, 248, 255);
  border:1px solid rgb(119, 172, 178);
}

.and {
  background-color: rgb(255, 240, 191);
  border:1px solid rgb(234, 216, 77);
}
```

HTML

```
<table id="searchable-table">
  <tr class="avoid">
    <th>Search:</th>
    <th colspan="2">
      <input id="search-input" type="text" placeholder="Search here..."/>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="avoid">
    <td>Case Insensitive:</td>
    <td colspan="2" class="text-left"><input id="caseinsensitive" type="checkbox" checked="checked"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="avoid">
    <td>Filters:</td>
    <td id="filter-preview" colspan="2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="avoid">
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Dept</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>BOB</td>
    <td>Sales</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>SALLY</td>
    <td>Sales</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>BOB</td>
    <td>HouseKeeping</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>SALLY</td>
    <td>HouseKeeping</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="avoid">
  <td id="results"colspan=3></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Javascript / jQuery

```
/* NOTE: To make rows hide, adjust the CSS by uncommenting line 24. */
$(document).on('keyup', '#search-input', function() {
    var rows = $('#searchable-table tr').not('.avoid'),
    caseInsensitive = ($('#caseinsensitive').is(":checked")), //Set to false if you would like for the searches to respect case sensitivity.
    query = parse_query((caseInsensitive === true ? $(this).val().toLowerCase():$(this).val())),
    results = filter_rows(rows, query, caseInsensitive);
    $('#results').empty().append(results+' record(s) found!');
});

$(document).on('change', '#caseinsensitive', function() {
    $('#search-input').trigger('keyup');
});

//Filters rows based on search conditions (Highlights Red - See: CSS row 21)
function filter_rows(rows, query, caseInsensitive) {
    var r = 0;

    if(rows.length > 0) { //Check if there are any rows at all.
        $.each(rows, function(e, k) { //Iterate rows.
            var td = $(this).children('td'), //Get child cells of current row.
            name = (caseInsensitive === true ? td[1].innerText.toLowerCase():td[1].innerText), //Get name in 2nd cell of current row.
            dept = (caseInsensitive === true ? td[2].innerText.toLowerCase():td[2].innerText); //Get dept in 3rd cell of current row.
            if(!jQuery.isEmptyObject(query.or)) { //Check if any OR values are available in the array.
                if(isMatching(name, query.or) || isMatching(dept, query.or)) { //If name or dept is found matching in the 'OR' values, show row.
                    if($(this).hasClass('hide')) { $(this).removeClass('hide'); }
                } else {
                    if(!jQuery.isEmptyObject(query.and)) {
                        if(isMatching(name, query.and) && isMatching(dept, query.and)) {
                            if($(this).hasClass('hide')) { $(this).removeClass('hide'); }
                        } else {
                            if(!$(this).hasClass('hide')) { $(this).addClass('hide'); }
                        }
                    } else {
                        if(!$(this).hasClass('hide')) { $(this).addClass('hide'); }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if(!jQuery.isEmptyObject(query.and)) {
                    if(isMatching(name, query.and) && isMatching(dept, query.and)) {
                        if($(this).hasClass('hide')) { $(this).removeClass('hide'); }
                    } else {
                        if(!$(this).hasClass('hide')) { $(this).addClass('hide'); }
                    }
                } else {
                    if(!$(this).hasClass('hide')) { $(this).addClass('hide'); }
                }
            }
        });
    }
    return r;
}


//Takes string and converts it to an object of arrays containing distinct AND + OR values seperately.
function parse_query(str) {
    var or = str.split(","),
    defaultOr = true, //If true, single value searches default as an 'OR' operator value.
    params = {
    'or':[],
    'and':[]
    };
    if((or.length - 1) > 0 || (str.split("+").length - 1) > 0) { //If any 'AND' or 'OR' parameters found in string.
        $.each(or, function(k,v) {
            var and = v.split("+");
            //If value contains any AND operators
            if((and.length - 1) > 0) {
                console.log('%o',and);
                if(and[0].trim().length > 0) { //If the first value is not empty, add it to the 'OR' operator value list.
                    params.and.push(and[0].trim());
                }
                and.splice(0,1); //Remove 'OR' value from array
                $.each(and, function(ka,va) { //Add additional 'AND' values if they exist in string.
                    if(va.trim().length > 0) {
                        params.and.push(va.trim());
                    }
                });
            } else {
                if(v.trim().length > 0) {
                    params.or.push(v.trim());
                }
            }
        });
    } else { //If no delimeters found, default value to an operator (Default: 'OR').
        if(str.trim().length > 0) { //If string is not empty.
            if(defaultOr) {
                params.or[0] = str.trim();
            } else {
                params.and[0] = str.trim();
            }
        }
    }
    populate_filter_preview(params);
    console.log('%o',params);
    return params;
}


//Populates Filter row with an example of the search that is filtering the rows.
function populate_filter_preview(params) {
    var p = $('#filter-preview');
    p.empty();
    if(params.or.length > 0 || params.and.length > 0) {
        if(params.or.length > 0) {
            $.each(params.or, function(k,v) {
                p.append('<span class="or">'+v+'</span>');
            });
        }
        if(params.and.length > 0) {
            $.each(params.and, function(k,v) {
                p.append('<span class="and">'+v+'</span>');
            });
        }
    } else {
        p.empty();
    }
}

//Simple short function to return boolean if string found in array.
function isMatching(s,a) {
    return ($.inArray(s,a) > -1);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Xonos/z87oqcf0/

The link above is a full example of the code above.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have checked the code you have supplied but unfortunalty is not quite what I am trying to achieve.  If I put in the search terms: bob, Sally+Housekeeping then the only row that is returned is ID 3, BOB, Housekeeping. Whereas I would expect ID 1, 3 and 4 to be returned.  I will continue to look at the supplied code to see if I can figure out how to achieve this.  Thanks

Comment: I have corrected the logic to appropriately match results based on this logic. I also added some trimming so that space padding is ignored. Check it out.

Comment: Instead of the multiple checks for `$(this).hasClass(...){ $(this).removeClass(...) }` (and inverse logic (`!$(this).hasClass(...){ $(this).addClass(...) }`) you can just use `$(this).toggleClass("hide", true);` (or `false`) and it will add/remove it as required.